# Un valor en un dataframe contiene varios valores separados con punto y coma

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo el siguiente dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
l = [['x', 'aa', 'aa;bb'],
      ['y', 'bb', 'aa;cc;dd'],
      ['z', 'cc', 'cc'],
      ['w', 'dd', 'aa;bb;cc;dd']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df
```

Cada valor de la columna 3 contiene varios valores de la columna 2 separados por ";".

Necesito contar los valores de la columna 2 que aparecen en cada valor de la columna 3.

Por ejemplo, el 1er valor de la columna 3 es "aa;bb", entonces mi conteo debe dar 2, el 4to valor de la columna 3 es 'aa;bb;cc;dd', el conteo debe dar 4.
Luego tengo que almacenar todos mis conteos en otra columna.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta. Es decir, primero deseas separar todos los elementos y luego contar los que tengan el caracter ; ???

Comment: Los valores de la columna 3 están formados por valores de la columna 2. Necesito contar cuantos valores de la columna 2 hay en cada valor de la columna 3. :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero esto se lo que buscas:

```
l = [['x', 'aa', 'aa;bb'],
      ['y', 'bb', 'aa;cc;dd'],
      ['z', 'cc', 'cc'],
      ['w', 'dd', 'aa;bb;cc;dd']] 

#Cuanto tiene de ancho y de alto.
eje_x = len(l[0])
eje_y = len(l)

for y in range(eje_y):
    for x in range(eje_x):
        if x == eje_x - 1:
            contador = len(l[y][x].split(";"))
            l[y].append(contador)
            
for a in l:
    print(a)
```

salida:

```
['x', 'aa', 'aa;bb', 2]
['y', 'bb', 'aa;cc;dd', 3]
['z', 'cc', 'cc', 1]
['w', 'dd', 'aa;bb;cc;dd', 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Podemos escribir una función que reciba como parámetro un elemento de la columna 2. Por ejemplo recibiría algo como `"aa;bb"`. Esa función debe retornar como resultado cuántos de esos elementos están en la columna 1.

La siguiente función haría ese trabajo:

```
def cuantos(lista):
  lista = lista.split(";")
  return sum(1 for elem in lista if elem in df[1].values)
```

Cómo funciona:

- Se separa la cadena recibida por el `";"`, para obtener una lista como `["aa", "bb"]`
- Se escribe una expresión generadora que va generando unos (1) por cada elemento que se encuentre en la primera columna de `df`.
- Se retorna la suma de esos 1.

Ahora habría que aplicar esta función a cada elemento de la columna 2. Esto lo hace el método `.map()` de pandas:

```
df[2].map(cuantos)
```

El resultado en este ejemplo sale:

```
0    2
1    3
2    1
3    4
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```

Puedes asignar esto a otra columna si quieres, por ejemplo:

```
>>> df["cuantos"] = df[2].map(cuantos)
>>> df
   0   1            2  cuantos
0  x  aa        aa;bb        2
1  y  bb     aa;cc;dd        3
2  z  cc           cc        1
3  w  dd  aa;bb;cc;dd        4
```